# Interruption exception with Apache Camel route from/to Apache Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a running instance of an Apache Kafka message broker which I want to use as start/end point of a camel route. When starting the route - which seems to work fine - I get an `InterruptedException` where I don't know how to fix that:

```
09:06:33.840 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[OLOG_INBOUND]] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=KafkaTrafoDataRoute, groupId=8563046a-15fa-48fe-858f-cfd68c7b921c] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
09:06:33.840 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[OLOG_INBOUND]] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=KafkaTrafoDataRoute, groupId=8563046a-15fa-48fe-858f-cfd68c7b921c] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
09:06:33.849 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[OLOG_INBOUND]] WARN org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer - Interrupted while consuming OLOG_INBOUND-Thread 0 from kafka topic. Caused by: [org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException - java.lang.InterruptedException]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.maybeThrowInterruptException(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:504)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:287)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:242)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:218)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:230)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:314)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1218)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1181)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.doRun(KafkaConsumer.java:293)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.run(KafkaConsumer.java:215)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    ... 16 common frames omitted
09:06:33.850 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[OLOG_INBOUND]] INFO org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer - Unsubscribing OLOG_INBOUND-Thread 0 from topic OLOG_INBOUND
09:06:33.850 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[OLOG_INBOUND]] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=KafkaTrafoDataRoute, groupId=8563046a-15fa-48fe-858f-cfd68c7b921c] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
09:06:33.850 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[OLOG_INBOUND]] DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer - Closing OLOG_INBOUND-Thread 0
```

The route is called from a main routine like this (Note: I try not to use Spring as it causes too many problems in my case):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

    try {
        camelContext.addRoutes(new MyKafkaRoute());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        camelContext.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the code of MyKafkaRoute:

```
public class MyKafkaRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private String consumerEndpoint = "kafka:TOPIC_NAME?"    //
            + "brokers=server:port"                   //
            + "&clientId=myKafkaRoute";

    private String emitterEndpoint  = "kafka:TOPIC_NAME?"   //
            + "brokers=server:port"                   //
            + "&clientId=myKafkaRoute";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from(consumerEndpoint) //
                .process(... processing ...) //
                .to(emitterEndpoint) //
                .onException(Exception.class) //
                .useOriginalMessage() //
                .handled(true) //
                .to("stream:out");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of my problems was my own fault:

In the main program above I start the consumer by

```
camelContext.start();
```

But immediately after this statement, the test program of mine ends causing the `InterruptedExecption`. I enhanced the code:

```
try {
    camelContext.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    camelContext.stop();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I am able to see messages being send to the broker.

Comment: Hi @WolfiG, Apache Camel sounds interesting! Do you mind sharing your use case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My use case is the following: I am working at a large accelerator facility. In such an accelerator, beam diagnostics instruments can be triggered to read the ion beam current in the accelerator. I use Apache Kafka as broker to take messages from other applications with requests for reading beam diagnostics (name of device, timing, etc.). The apache route runs in the framework of the accelerator control system and calls code doing the actual readout. The readout values are being passed back to Kafka where the readout data can be picked up by other applications.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like (at least) one of the endpoints might not be available. Other than that, trim down the camel route to from(). ... .to(). ... .to() to get a clearer picture of what is being sent to whom.